# How to use parent column inside group concat subquery in mysql?

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I am new to mysql. I want to use parent column in sub query within group concat().

I have a following query.

```
select parenttable.id,
parenttable.name,
group_concat
(
    case when parenttable.id=1 then
    (
    select childtable.name, from c_table childtable 
    where childtable.id=parenttable.id
    )

    case when parenttable.id=2 then
    (
    select childtable.name from c_table childtable 
    where childtable.id=parenttable.id
    ) 

    end;

)
from p_table parenttable
```

The above query shows "Unknown column parenttable.id" . Is there any solution to fix it.

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you actually have column `id` in p_table? What if you remove group_concat from query? will it work?

Comment: Yes it is available. after removing group concat it is working.

Comment: Your subquery should return only one column. So depending in your needs concat childtable.id and childtable.name or remove one of them

Comment: ok. i removed. but still shows same error. kindly look my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using join ...

```
SELECT id,name,GROUP_CONCAT(GP_ID) FROM
     (
      select parenttable.id,
        parenttable.name,
        group_concat(
            case when parenttable.id=1 then
            concat(childtable.id,',',childtable.name)
             when parenttable.id=2 then
          concat(childtable.id,',',childtable.name)
         ELSE NULL  
         end
        ) AS GP_ID
        from p_table  parenttable LEFT OUTER JOIN
        c_table childtable
        ON
        childtable.id=parenttable.id
    GROUP BY parenttable.id 
)  A
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. No. I dont need outer join. I just want to use subquery inside group concat.

Comment: try moving group_concat inside subquery

Comment: Please look my question again. That's what i actually need.

Comment: Sorry. Unfortunately I need to use it inside group concat. Is there any other possible?

Comment: adding concat to you columns in subquery may help .Try this.

Comment: Same issue. Is that proper way to get id from parenttable in above query? or the query itself has a problem?

Comment: Sorry Gooner. It is not working. I need where conditions inside group concat. Is there any other possible ?

Comment: The problem will be for your single id in parent  will be having multiple id's in child ,then  it will cause subquery returns multiple row error. To avoid this you have to group_concat the result from the subquery to a single row by moving the group_concat function inside the case statement.